# Varying page size of maps within an Atlas in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, atlas

I would like to create an atlas of a series of maps covering a number of woodlands and to have them all at the same map scale.

This would work best visually if some of the maps were in landscape, and some were in portrait orientation.

Is it possible to do this, or do all maps within an atlas have to have the same paper size and orientation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Page properties of the layout (Right click the map) you can set the Orientation using an expression.

```
 if( bounds_height(  @atlas_geometry )> bounds_width(@atlas_geometry )  , 'portrait', 'landscape')
```

and presto it switches depending on the aspect ratio of the atlas feature.

You may also need to move elements of the layout around this can be done using expressions like `if(  "orient"  =  'Landscape' ,210,297)` in the X or Y boxes of the Position and Size section of the individual elements.

Answer (score 1):

The expression if("orient" = 'landscape', 210, 297)
always returns False for me, leading me to think that orient, landscape or both are no longer assigned variables in QGIS 3.34.

Using if(bounds_height(@atlas_geometry) > bounds_width(@atlas_geometry), 210, 297)

does work for moving elements around the print layout and returns True or False appropriately.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's Landscape with a capital L